# Preprocess Highchart data using CSV file

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to preprocess data using CSV file. **After the page loaded, ask to browse the CSV file, and then preprocess it to page.**
[I'm using this chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic). I would be grateful if you help me get through this. I just know HTML + CSS Basics and don't know how to put this together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data on desktop you can try the following solutions as a base:

***1. Solution with [jQuery-csv.js](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/)***

You can do it with different CSV parsing libraries. To do it add  control to the page and add loadFile() function like in the example below:

```
<input id="readfile" type="file" onchange="loadFile(event)"/>
<script>
function loadFile(event) {
        var files = event.target.files;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var name = files[0].name;
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            processCSV(data);
        };
        reader.readAsText(files[0]);    
};

function processCSV(data) {
     // 1. Convert CSV text from "data" parameter to JSON
      var arr = $.csv.toArray(data);
     // 2. Prepare chart from "arr" array
};
</script>
```

***2. Solution with [Alasql.js](http://github.com/agershun/alasql)***

Alternative solution with Alasql.js library (it includes file uploading and CSV-parsing functions):

```
<input id="readfile" type="file" onchange="loadFile(event)"/>
<script>
function loadFile(event) {
    alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{headers:true})', [event],function(data){
         // Process your data
    });
);
</script>
```

Here:

1. You need to create  button in the page to select CSV.
2. Add event function to this button and pass "event" as a parameter (loadFile(event) in the example)
3. Pass this event as parameter to loading function (FILE() or CSV() or XLSX() in the example).
4. Process result data and prepare them for Highcharts.

You can run working snippet with Highcharts below. Before prepare the chart create file demo.csv (by hand) from the end of the snippet and save it to desktop.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) library)

```js
         function loadFile(event) {
             alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{headers:true})',[event],function(data){

               // Process your data here
               var myseries = [];
                Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(function(key){
                    var ds = data.map(function(d){ return +d[key];});
                   myseries.push({name:key,data:ds});
                });

               // Prepare data for Hightcharts.js
                $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: myseries
            });

             
             
             
             
             
             });
         }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://alasql.org/console/alasql.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>     

     <p>Select CSV file to read</p>
     <input id="readfile" type="file" onchange="loadFile(event)"/>
     <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<h3>Sample file demo.csv</h3>
<pre>
Paris, London
111,211
321,411
512,611
710,811
1121,222
300,422
500,622
700,822
100,222
300,422
511,622
711,811
</pre>
```

Comment: Yes sir, this is what I exactly needed. But I don't know how match the created button and event ... This is too complicated for me. Do you know a simple file uploaded somewhere using this method? With this library: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic
I inspected this page: http://www.highcharts.com/studies/data-module-csv.htm and created the exact files, but didn't worked!

Comment: 1. Can you run the example in the code snippet with this file? https://cdn.rawgit.com/agershun/alasql/version-0.0.37/examples/csv/data.csv  It should work. 2. If you specify <input type="file" onchange="loadFile(event)"> in HTML, then browser will fire loadFile() function with event as a parameter. And event.target.files is a list of selected files.

Comment: I look at the link (highcharts.com/studies/data-module-csv.htm). 1. The difference that they load CSV file from the server with $.get() function, but in my answer browser loads data from desktop. Unfortunately, the code is different in this case 2. Probably (I am not sure), Highcharts can accept CSV data as a string (as it shown in example), but for additional processing you need to convert it to JS array.

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you so much. It should be so hard, how can I learn and do it on my own? I just started with w3shools JavaScript tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand well, you can use this scenario

1) run website and call upload function

2) save file on your server

3) load csv by $.get() and parse values to create series object

4) initialise chart

Comment: It's on local and I dont know how to put stuff together.

Comment: To load a file, you need ot have webserver, because browsers block, loading files from local file system.